# Request to merge [tongues] and [speaking-in-tongues]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have two tags, [tongues](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tongues) (14 questions) and [speaking-in-tongues](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking-in-tongues) (7 questions), which both describe [glossolalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossolalia). Would it be possible to have these merged?

My personal preference would be to have [speaking-in-tongues](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking-in-tongues) be the primary tag with [tongues](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tongues) becoming a tag synonym, since "speaking in tongues" is the phrase used on the [Glossolalia Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossolalia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As you wish.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest)